# Import Famo.us Ember-Cli project

Tags: ember-cli

I am trying to import famous into my application

When i create a breakpoint in the base index.html file in ember cli and look at what require seems to know about i see famo.us is there[image]

in my brocfile i have tried the following

```
app.import('vendor/famous/famous.js', {
    'famous/core/Context':''
});

app.import('vendor/famous/famous.js', {
    'famous/core/Context':'default'
});

app.import('vendor/famous/famous.js');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may be fixed by master of loader.js https://github.com/stefanpenner/loader.js/issues/25

Comment: awesomeness it does fix it :)